# How to mimic passing of ES6 rest parameters in a class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm having trouble trying to recreate [this functional component](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow) using an ES6 class equivalent:

Example usage: `<PrivateRoute path="/protected" component={Protected}/>`

**React Function example**

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={props => (
    fakeAuth.isAuthenticated ? (
      <Component {...props}/>
    ) : (
      <Redirect to={{
        pathname: '/login',
        state: { from: props.location }
      }}/>
    )
  )}/>
)
```

Here's what I have so far, not sure how to get the {...rest} (in other words the params passed to PrivateRoute into my class:

**ES6 Class** - trying to do the equiv

*Note*: in mine I'm going to be getting isAuthenticated passed via mapStateToProps since this is really a connected component. I just left connect out of this because I'm concentrating on how to re-create the function via ES6 class for this stack post.

import React,  { Component } from 'react'

```
export class PrivateRoute extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }
  render() {
    const { from } = this.props.location.state || { from: { pathname: '/' } }

    return (
      <Route
        {...rest}
        component={this.props.component}
        render={props =>
          (this.props.isAuthenticated ? (<Component {...props} />) :
          (<Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: '/login',
              state: {from: this.props.location
              }}}
          />))}
      />)
  }
}
```

**some things I'm not sure about**:

- what `props` stands for in `render=( props =>`..  I know it's a param but what kind of param is it?  Where's the value coming from for props?  Is it a way to get at the props of the PrivateRoute component...that it's just passing it down to the  is all that's doing?  why can't you access props inside ?  probably because it would be referring to the Route's props if it wasn't explicitly passed?
- I'm getting a `missing import statement` for `Component` on this line:
  `<Component {...props} />`
- I don't know how to pass `{...rest}` such as in the functional example in the case where I have a class
- any other syntax issues you might see that I'm not seeing here

***UPDATE***

I *think* I got it, we'll see once I run my tests

```
export class ProtectedRouteContainer extends Component {

  render() {
    const { from } = this.props.location.state || { from: { pathname: '/' } }

    return (
      <Route
        {...this.props}
        component={Component}
        render={props =>
          (this.props.isAuthenticated ? (<props.component {...props} />) :
          (<Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: '/login',
              state: {from: this.props.location
              }}}
          />))}
      />)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are passing props into a `class` component then you would reference the `props` as `this.rest`. Then you could spread them out into your child component as `{...this.rest}`. I don't know about how `props` is being passed but I think this answers your original question about how to pass the `rest` props. This answer depends on if you are passing the props to this component as `rest` or `...rest`.

Comment: is rest a generic term here?

Comment: crap look up again, it wasn't showing the "Example usage:" now it does so you can see what's being passed.  I mean ...rest looks like it's simply passing the rest of the props passed to <ProtectedRoute ... />

Comment: also check out my second stab at it, I updated the post

Comment: If you instantiate the component and pass down something like this `<Component rest={...props} />` then inside of your component you would do `{...this.rest}` but if  you are just doing `<Component {...props} />` then all you would need to do is `{...this.props}`. It just depends on how you name your props.

Comment: thanks Adam...I see now.  So it's like  taking the Component's props, assigning to rest, then spreading the rest param out.  Since ...rest is spreading out ...props, through destructuring, I can reference whatever ...props is via 'props' again?  I'm not that advanced yet with destructuring, just done basic destructuring so that's why it was hard for me to understand.

Comment: With you functional component, you are saying, whatever other props that I pass to this component, they will be assigned to `rest`.

Comment: yea i get the functional one in terms of what the initial {...rest} was.  I just didn't know how you'd pass it via class.  and I was also getting lost once it started to be used inside <Route

Comment: Yes, that is essentially what you are doing. It's basically pattern matching.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145402/discussion-between-adam-recvlohe-and-positiveguy).